# Calculating volume for sphere in C++

Tags: c++

This is probably an easy one, but is the right way to calculate volume for a sphere in C++?  My `getArea()` seems to be right, but when I call `getVolume()` it doesn't output the right amount.  With a sphere of `radius = 1`, it gives me the answer of `pi`, which is incorrect:

```
double Sphere::getArea() const
{
    return 4 * Shape::pi * pow(getZ(), 2);
}

double Sphere::getVolume() const
{
    return (4 / 3) * Shape::pi * pow(getZ(), 3);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're using integer division in `(4 / 3)`.  Instead, use floating point division: `(4.0 / 3.0)`.

`4/3` is 1, because integer division only produces integers.  You can confirm this by test code: `std::cout << (4/3) << std::endl;`.

Comment: +1 Yup, getVolume might as well be (and may even be optimized to) `Shape::pi * pow(getZ(), 3)`.

Comment: @Nathan, you meant by the compiler, right? Otherwise the formula would have been horribly inaccurate for calculating volumes.

Comment: @Xavier, yes I meant optimized by the compiler. ;) Obviously the formula would otherwise be in correct.

Answer (score 4):

In `(4 / 3)`, these are both integers so you get integer division. That means the result will be truncated (1.333... becomes 1). Make one of them a double so the other gets promoted to a double during division, yielding a correct result.

I prefer to use `(4.0 / 3.0)`.

Answer (score 3):

(4 / 3) is an integer expression and is therefore being truncated to 1. Try (4.0 / 3.0)